# Setup Wix/Detox - run their react native example

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, detox

Detox from Wix looks like a VERY useful tool and I have been eager to try it out. Tried to follow the [README in the demo-react-native folder](https://github.com/wix/Detox/tree/5988a278762b00f1b45352a789b32b902760f85b/examples/demo-react-native) but I think it's a bit outdated.

As mentioned I cant get it to work. Here is what I believe is missing in the README

- `npm install -g detox-cli` - missing
- `detox init --runner jest` - missing

I have tried to set my `.detoxrc.json` to

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But running `npm start` in one terminal and `detox build -c ios` throws this

```
$ detox build -c ios
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] DetoxConfigError: Could not find a build script inside "ios" configuration.
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] 
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] HINT: Check contents of your Detox config at path:
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] /Users/norfeldt/Desktop/Detox/examples/demo-react-native/.detoxrc.json
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] 
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] {
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]   configurations: {
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]     ios: {
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]       type: 'ios.simulator',
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]       binaryPath: 'ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app',
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]       device: [Object]
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]     }
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js]   }
detox[89936] ERROR: [cli.js] }
```

running  `detox build --configuration ios.sim.release` (as stated in the **README**) throws this:

```
$ detox build --configuration ios.sim.release
detox[91765] ERROR: [cli.js] DetoxConfigError: Failed to find a configuration named "ios.sim.release" in Detox config at path:
detox[91765] ERROR: [cli.js] /Users/norfeldt/Desktop/Detox/examples/demo-react-native/.detoxrc.json
detox[91765] ERROR: [cli.js] 
detox[91765] ERROR: [cli.js] HINT: Below are the configurations Detox was able to find:
detox[91765] ERROR: [cli.js] * ios
```

Would have made a PR for the things I think is missing it but want to make sure it all works first - which I can't get it to.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the demo projects are no longer maintained for iOS. You are better off creating a new RN project, integrating Detox following our documentation, and start adding your first test.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's just that the current README links to this demo folder. Can't see any statements that they are being deprecated. Is this the Detox documentation you are referring to https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md

Comment: I’m referring to my state of mind as the sole maintainer of Detox for iOS. 

Comment: it looks like an awesome project and I would have loved to try it out. But my homebrew is messed up when trying to install it and Homebrew can't help me. So it will be some other time, unfortunately

Comment: Your homebrew installation is broken. I'd suggest fixing that regardless of Detox, as a lot of software relies on that on macOS.

Comment: I agree on that and working hard to figure out how to fix that